# Android Spinner Initial Padding

Tags: android

I am creating an Android app that consists mainly of a form.  This form needs to have `EditText` and `Spinners` side-by-side (for this I chose a `LinearLayout`). **My final goal is to have the text in the `Spinner` align vertically with the text in the `EditText`**; however, I also want to have padding on the options in the expanded `Spinner`.  This padding messes up the `Spinner` alignment as it appears in the form.

Here is my code for a custom `Spinner` list item:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/transportation_spinner_item_textView"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:textSize="18dp"/>
```

Here is my code for the main form:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/divider3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ip_minutes_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/ip_minutes"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/ip_minutes_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:gravity="bottom"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/ip_charge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            android:editable="false"
            android:hint="@string/ip_charge"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is an image of how it looks:
[Image of alignment with above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkDta.jpg)

I have been Googling and trying to adjust the padding/margins of different views for hours, so if anyone has any suggestions, that would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand, when you say,

> This padding messes up the Spinner alignment as it appears in the
>   form.

Do you mean the DropDownView? that shows when the Spinner is clicked?

If so, simply create a separate layout for the DropDownView.

In your ArrayAdapter you will have the following methods,

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt)

public View getView(int pos, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt)
```

Just have them return two different Views, e.g

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
    return getCustomDropDownView(position, cnvtView, prnt);
}
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
    return getCustomView(pos, cnvtView, prnt);
}
```

and

```
public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    View mySpinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);

    TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.spinner_text);
    main_text.setText(spinnerValues[position]);

    return mySpinner;
}

public View getCustomDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    View mySpinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dropdown_spinner, parent, false);

    TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.spinner_text);
    main_text.setText(spinnerValues[position]);

    return mySpinner;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  Thank you, kind sir.